# called object type 'void (B::*)(int)' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to wrap my head around passing method as function argument. Here is a simplified example which returns a compilation error that I don't understand

```
class B
{
private:
    int j;
public:
    void foo(int i){std::cout << i + this->j << std::endl;}
    void setj(int J){j=J;}
};

class A
{
private:
    B b;

public:
    void call(void (B::*fun)(int i), int i) { b.*fun(i); }
    void setBj(int j){b.setj(j);}
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.setBj(40);
    a.call(B::foo, 2);
}
```

When compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++11 b.cpp -o b
```

I get

```
b.cpp:22:50: error: called object type 'void (B::*)(int)' is not a function or
      function pointer
        void call(void (B::*fun)(int i), int i) { b.*fun(i); }
                                                     ~~~^
b.cpp:31:12: error: call to non-static member function without an object
      argument
        a.call(B::foo, 2);
               ~~~^~~
2 errors generated.
```

I don't understand the first error message. I understand that I am calling `foo` as if it was a static method, which it is not but I don't understand how to pass a non-static method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems.

1. To invoke a pointer to a member function, you need to first apply a pointer to member access operator, that obtains a callable expression. Then you add a call. Now it just so happens that `.*` is of lower precedence than the function call operator. So the first fix:

   ```
   (b.*fun)(i)
   ```
2. A a pointer to member function can only be obtained by applying unary `&` on the fully qualified function name. So the second fix:

   ```
   a.call(&B::foo, 2);
   ```